# Executing JavaScript with Python without X

Tags: javascript, python

I want to parse a html-page that unfortunately requires JavaScript to show any content. In order to do so I use a small python-script that pulls the html-code of the page, but after that I have to execute the JavaScript in a DOM-context which seems pretty hard.

To make it even harder I want to use it in a server environment that has no X11-server.

Note: I already read about http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/ but it seems to need a X-server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate a browser environment using [EnvJS](http://www.envjs.com/).  However, in order to make use of it, you will have to embed some kind of JavaScript runtime (e.g. [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/)) in your program (or spawn one as an external process).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) to have a fake frame buffer, so you won't need to run X11 (though it may be a dependency of Xvfb on your system). Most rendering engines don't have a headless mode, so something like Xvfb is necessary to run them. I used this technique successfully using XULRunner to navigate web pages, though not from python.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still trying to figure this out myself, so take my answer with a grain of salt.

So far, I found http://blog.motane.lu/2009/06/18/pywebkitgtk-execute-javascript-from-python/, which describes the use and the quirks of Pywebkitgtk by someone who has similar needs to what we do.

Later, however, the writer of that blogpost discovered that he can't get it to work with Xvbf, so he hunted some more and found a Qt webkit (possibly in Qt itself, if I understand correctly) http://blog.motane.lu/2009/07/07/downloading-a-pages-content-with-python-and-webkit/.  Apparently it's a much better solution than PywebkitGTK.

Naturally, I'll be looking into the other solutions offered here--but I wanted to bring up the Qt solution, because to me, it seems the most likely candidate for what I want to do...and if not, then perhaps it will be for someone else, looking for an answer to this question! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use VNC or Xvfb for this purpose, combined with Firefox. After experimenting with the two, I settled on [XTightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/). We use it to create screenshots on demand for various test purposes. It's nice to use one of these because you're executing it in an actual browser, same as a user would be (though most users probably won't be using the same OS as your server).

The handy thing about using VNC is that you can connect remotely to set up and test the browser when needed.

Comment: I don't the graphical output, I just need to receive the HTML-code after executing JS.

Comment: @Thomas it doesn't make a difference. In my testing, VNC is equivalent to Xvfb, except you have the option of graphical output.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/

Comment: Isn't V8 just a JavaScript engine? As I said, I need DOM.